# realm save objects but don't retrieve it on other thread?

Tags: android, realm

`Realm Version : 5.11.0`
`Kotlin vesion : 1.3.31`

`minSdkVersion 21`
`targetSdkVersion 28`
`compileSdkVersion 28`

## Resume the problem

insert objects on realm database, displaying them well in this context but and can't get same result after run again the same class

## What i tried

refresh or close realm after my transaction without success

ContactObserver is background class, it job is to synchronize contacts, and it
extends : ContentObserver

## Show me code !!

Before we wanna assert our contacts, let's display number of
contacts to assert :

```
Log.i("okhttp","assert contact : " + Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(ContactStatus::class.java).equalTo("toAssert", true).findAll().size) 
/*
It will log : 453 contacts to assert

Now we give all these contacts as input to graphQl request,

On GraphQl response, we open transaction a big transaction and for each contact asserted and we display again the number of total contacts
to assert :
*/

Realm.getDefaultInstance().executeTransaction {

// delete and insert contactStatus with data 

contactStatus.deleteFromRealm()
it.insertOrUpdate(ContactStatus(data.contact, true,false,false,false))

// and we log among of contacts to assert after this
Log.i("okhttp"," assert : " + Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(ContactStatus::class.java).equalTo("toAssert", true).findAll().size)

// in each value of foreach, we saw the total value descreasing 

/*

I/okhttp:  assert : 452
I/okhttp:  assert : 451
I/okhttp:  assert : 450
I/okhttp:  assert : 449
I/okhttp:  assert : 448
I/okhttp:  assert : 447
I/okhttp:  assert : 446
I/okhttp:  assert : 445
I/okhttp:  assert : 444
I/okhttp:  assert : 443
I/okhttp:  assert : 442
I/okhttp:  assert : 441
I/okhttp:  assert : 440
    ...
I/okhttp:  assert : 14


*/

}

// then we close the default instance
Realm.getDefaultInstance().close()


// Now when we launch again this class, final result should be 14 contacts to assert

Log.i("okhttp","assert contact : " + Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(ContactStatus::class.java).equalTo("toAssert", true).findAll().size)

// But it displays again 453, here is the issue, it should display 14
```

## Goal

insert objects on realm database properly once and display total size

## Actual Results

in certain context objects seems to be saved when we log them, but after certain time when we change context it don't save anything

## EDIT

with some modifications, maybe the issue is due to grahQl RxJava background threading ?

here is the full piece of code i'm using, that don't save properly datas on realm when i display it on main thread of application :

```
    NvGraphQLClient.createService(ContactService::class.java).assertContact(builder)
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .subscribe(object : DisposableObserver<GraphContainer<SingleResponse<AssertContact>>>() {

                        override fun onComplete() {

                            val r = Realm.getDefaultInstance()

                            r.refresh()

                            if (r.where(ContactStatus::class.java).equalTo("toAssert", true).findAll().size > 0) {
                                Log.i("okhttp", "complete assert : " + r.where(ContactStatus::class.java).equalTo("toAssert", true).findAll().size)
                                assertContact()
                                r.refresh()
                            }
                            else {
                                r.refresh()
                                Log.i("okhttp", "complete assert : " + r.where(ContactStatus::class.java).equalTo("toAssert", true).findAll().size)
                            }
                            r.close()
                        }

                        override fun onNext(response: GraphContainer<SingleResponse<AssertContact>>) {


                            if (response.data.item != null) {

                                val assertsData = response.data.item.assertData

                                val r = Realm.getDefaultInstance()

                                r.executeTransaction {

                                    assertsData?.forEach { data ->
                                        if ((data.assert == 0) || (data.assert == 2)) {

                                                    contactStatus.deleteFromRealm()
                                                    it.insertOrUpdate(ContactStatus(data.contact, true,false,false,false))
                                                    Log.i("okhttp"," assert after compute : " + Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(ContactStatus::class.java).equalTo("toAssert", true).findAll().size)
                                                }
                                                else {
                                                    Log.i("okhttp", "contact null" + data.contact.toString())
                                                }

                                            }
                                            else
                                                Log.i("okhttp", "mid null" + data.contact?.mid)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                r.refresh()
                            }

                        }

                        override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                            Log.e("okhttp", e.message)
                        }
                    })
```

## maybe issue can be due to graphQl background working ?

here is the full piece of code with some modifications :

```
  NvGraphQLClient.createService(ContactService::class.java).assertContact(builder)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(object : DisposableObserver<GraphContainer<SingleResponse<AssertContact>>>() {

                    override fun onComplete() {

                        val r = Realm.getDefaultInstance()

                        r.refresh()

                        if (r.where(ContactStatus::class.java).equalTo("toAssert", true).findAll().size > 0) {
                            Log.i("okhttp", "complete assert : " + r.where(ContactStatus::class.java).equalTo("toAssert", true).findAll().size)
                            assertContact()
                            r.refresh()
                        }
                        else {
                            r.refresh()
                            Log.i("okhttp", "complete assert : " + r.where(ContactStatus::class.java).equalTo("toAssert", true).findAll().size)
                        }
                        r.close()
                    }

                    override fun onNext(response: GraphContainer<SingleResponse<AssertContact>>) {


                        if (response.data.item != null) {

                            val assertsData = response.data.item.assertData

                            val r = Realm.getDefaultInstance()

                            r.executeTransaction {

                                assertsData?.forEach { data ->
                                    if ((data.assert == 0) || (data.assert == 2)) {

                                                contactStatus.deleteFromRealm()
                                                it.insertOrUpdate(ContactStatus(data.contact, true,false,false,false))
                                                Log.i("okhttp"," assert after compute : " + Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(ContactStatus::class.java).equalTo("toAssert", true).findAll().size)
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                Log.i("okhttp", "contact null" + data.contact.toString())
                                            }

                                        }
                                        else
                                            Log.i("okhttp", "mid null" + data.contact?.mid)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            r.refresh()
                        }

                    }

                    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                        Log.e("okhttp", e.message)
                    }
                })
```

I noticed this issue only on Android 8 device but can't reproduce on Android 9, on Android 9 its workin well

I modified too my ContentObserver class maybe i had some issue with executing realm on this context, so i write again my request but in a regular activity (my HomeActivity), so when i'm launching my function to assert, all seems working well, i have the same value when a run again my function untill i finish to save datas, but when i launch again my application, i loose all my datas saved on realm, and i have to run again my assert from beggining...

## What i tried too :

- Use Subscribers.newThread() instead of Subscribers.io() without success, related to this question :

[Realm data sync not consistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39138108/realm-data-sync-not-consistent)

- Refresh realm before & after my read or write from base without success
- Take care of close realm instances after use it, even if it's supposed to be supported when i launch execute transaction (supposed to be closed automatically after execution) without success

Answer (score 0):

Finally it wasn't due to realm, my code created new elements at execution automatically, so this is fixed